# How to convert a column of type Series to datetime weekdays format in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, datetime-format

I have the following data and python code

```
Time Started    Date Submitted  Status
10/29/2015 17:34    10/29/2015 17:34    Complete
10/29/2015 17:35    10/29/2015 17:35    Complete
10/29/2015 17:36    10/29/2015 17:37    Complete

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
datetime.strptime(df['Date Submitted'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strptime('%A')
```

When I try to run the following code I get a TypeError message. I just 
 trying to convert the column data of type series to datetime weekdays 
 format

> datetime.strptime(df['Session Submitted'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strptime('%A')
>   TypeError: must be string, not Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert to `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Time Started,Date Submitted,Status
10/29/2015 17:34,10/29/2015 17:34,Complete
10/29/2015 17:35,10/29/2015 17:35,Complete
10/29/2015 17:36,10/29/2015 17:37,Complete"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0,1])
print (df)
         Time Started      Date Submitted    Status
0 2015-10-29 17:34:00 2015-10-29 17:34:00  Complete
1 2015-10-29 17:35:00 2015-10-29 17:35:00  Complete
2 2015-10-29 17:36:00 2015-10-29 17:37:00  Complete

print (df.dtypes)
Time Started      datetime64[ns]
Date Submitted    datetime64[ns]
Status                    object
dtype: object
```

Then use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date Submitted'] = df['Date Submitted'].dt.strftime('%A')
print (df)
         Time Started Date Submitted    Status
0 2015-10-29 17:34:00       Thursday  Complete
1 2015-10-29 17:35:00       Thursday  Complete
2 2015-10-29 17:36:00       Thursday  Complete
```

Another solution is [`dt.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html) (new in version 0.18.1):

```
df['Date Submitted'] = df['Date Submitted'].dt.weekday_name
print (df)
         Time Started Date Submitted    Status
0 2015-10-29 17:34:00       Thursday  Complete
1 2015-10-29 17:35:00       Thursday  Complete
2 2015-10-29 17:36:00       Thursday  Complete
```

Comment: Thank  You Jezrael! Your answer was very helpful!